# Angular Cookies: Error: Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, dependencies, bower

have problems integrating angular-cookies because it keeps throwing an unkown provider error.

Here is the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies <- $cookieStore <- coreRequestErrorHandler <- $http <- $translatePartialLoader <- $cookies
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24cookieReader%20%3C-%20%24cookies%20%3C-%20%24cookieStore%20%3C-%20coreRequestErrorHandler%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24translatePartialLoader%20%3C-%20%24cookies
```

here is my bower.js configuration:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular-translate": "2.8.1",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.8.1",
"angular-translate-loader-url": "2.8.1",
"angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.8.1",
"angular": "1.4.7",
"angular-route": "^1.4.x",
"angular-resource": "^1.4.x",
"angular-animate": "^1.4.x",
"angular-sanitize": "^1.4.x",
"jquery": "~2.1.1",
"leaflet": "latest",
"angular-leaflet-directive": "0.7.11",
"angular-simple-logger": "0.1.5",
"Leaflet.label": "latest",
"leaflet.markercluster": "latest",
"ng-file-upload": "9.1.0",
"foundation": "5.5.3",
"angular-jwt": "0.0.9",
"angular-cookies": "1.4.7",
"moment-range": "2.0.3",
"angular-i18n": "^1.4.7",
"angular-local-storage": "~0.2.2"
}
```

so angular and angluar-cookies have the same version level installment.

in my module i include it like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

 angular.module("sep.auth", ['LocalStorageModule', 'ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

})();
```

in my Service the cookie-module is used as following:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('sep.auth').provider('authService', authServiceProvider);

  authServiceProvider.$inject = [];

  function authServiceProvider() {

      this.$get = authService;

      authService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'jwtHelper', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$location', '$log', 'localStorageService', 'AuthMapModuleService', '$resource'];

      function authService($http, $q, jwtHelper, $cookies, $cookieStore ,$rootScope, $location, $log, localStorageService, AuthMapModuleService, $resource) {

          ...
    }

}
```

Could it have something to do with the fact that $cookieStore is deprecated? The angular-cookies dependency works with version 1.3.9 but not above.

Could someone help me what I am missing? We just want to update our package resouces and it would be strange if we use angular version 1.4.7 but angular-cookies version 1.3.9.

Comment: Did you run npm install or did you run bower install from the console?

Comment: we run the npm and the bower install both from the console. we have both npm and bower for installing dependencies.